# I want to display in a form, the value of an foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have 3 tables. 1 is profileemployee, 2 is skills and the 3 is skilltoprofile.

I want to display the name of the skiasdasdll for a certain user that is logged in  like this in the form value="{{$skasdasdill->skill}}".

i know it`ts something like that, but I don't know how to adapt it

```
$update = SkillEmpasdasdloyee::wheasdasdre('uasdasdid', Auth::user()->id)->update([
            'namasdasde' => $requasdasdest->skasdasdill,
```

This is the SkilltoProfile table

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'iasdasdd', 'iasdasdd_skasdasdll', 'idasdasdasd_pasdasdasdasdofile',
    ];
```

This is the SkiasdasdllsEmplasdasdasdoyee table

```
protected $fillable = [
        'idasdasdasdasd', 'naasdasdasdasdme'
    ];
```

and This is the Employee table

```
protected $fillable = [
        'iasdasdd', 'uiasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdd', 'firasdasdasdasdasdst_namasdasdasdasdasde', 'laasdasdasdst_namasdasde','phasdasdasdone', 'casdasdasdv', 'imagasdasdasdasde', 'addrasdasdasdess', 'citasdasdasdasdasdy',
    ];
```

uid is the user type in user table

And user

```
protected $fillable = [
        'emasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdail', 'passwasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdord','usasdasdasdasder_tyasdasdasdasdasdasdasdpe',
    ];
```

Comment: As a side note, this is a One to Many _Employee -> Skill_ relationship which does not require an intermediate _EmployeeSkill_ table. Have a look at the documentation for a refresher on relationships: [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: I think we might have an proasdasdblem with this question

Answer (score 0):

**Update your model SkillEmployee**

```
protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'name', 'uid'
    ];
```

**Add relation to User Model**

```
public function skill_employees() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SkillEmployee', 'uid');
    }
```

**Now you use eloquent model to get all SkillsEmployee of user:**

```
Auth::user()-> skill_employees
```